# Is Karma absolutely necessary to run Angular 2 unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

If this is a silly question, I apologize, but I am sincerely having a hard time understanding if we absolutely need Karma to run unit tests? I am new to Angular 2, Karma and Jasmine, and I was hoping someone with more experience than me could explain if we could just use Jasmine standalone to run unit tests.

I know that Karma is a test runner, and I know all the niceties that come with Karma (test on multiple browsers and devices, automatically rerun tests when files are changed, test coverage results, easy integration with Jenkins .. the list goes on and on!). But I am just having a hard time understanding if it completely necessary. A lot of the examples I've seen (if not all of them) use Karma, but I have not seen an example where only Jasmine is used, and would like an explanation why. Is it because of how Karma loads the spec/app files?

An example I was looking at was Jasmine standalone, and I am trying to use this example to apply to my current structure, but so far no luck:
https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: It's not necessary. You know before the testing docs was revamped, they didn't even have a karma example. It was only a Jasmine example. You can try to navigate [the old docs (source)](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/tree/jun21/public/docs/ts/latest/testing).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I unfortunately never saw the test example before Karma. I found the link here http://web.archive.org/web/20160603181922/https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html